# Multi-lined command output set as variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

So I've googled and searched stackflow; I think the output for the library I'm using and the way it's structured makes none of the answers work.

I downloaded a windows library called totp2 for command prompt. I am executing the command in my batch file and that works fine, but it wants to return the line I passed.

I'm looking to run the command, and only assign the very last line to a variable; *stripping the word `OTP:` from the last line.*

```
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\devBash> t2otp.exe QQRZO4QIGPJFXS2QXDIL4JUO2KKQCPTOF2D5AX5M3R2VH5NM2ZUSXIXGP4WPMVTR sha256 6 30

T2OTP v2 - Command line TOTP Generator (c) TOKEN2
Algorithm: sha256
Seed: QQRZO4QIGPJFXS2QXDIL4JUO2KKQCPTOF2D5AX5M3R2VH5NM2ZUSXIXGP4WPMVTR
Interval: 30 seconds
OTP length: 6 digits
    
OTP: 666323
```

The above is exactly how it returns the command prompt results, with the code being on line 7 of the command output.

Current Code (hardcoded command just for testing):

```
For /F "EOL=/" %%A In ('t2otp.exe QQRZO4QIGPJFXS2QXDIL4JUO2KKQCPTOF2D5AX5M3R2VH5NM2ZUSXIXGP4WPMVTR sha256 6 30') Do Set "totp=%%A"
```

However that returns just `OTP:`

**Current Result:**

```
OTP: 666323
```

**Needed Result:**

```
666323
```

Any help is really really appreciated.

*And yes; it's a demo secret.*

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2delims=: " %%A...` should derive that data

Comment: Wow..... so simple... I tried about 5 different versions of tokens and delims, and just went back to read the docs again.... Thanks... a bunch <3

Answer (score 1):

```
For /F "Tokens=2 eol=/" %%A In ('t2otp.exe QQRZO4QIGPJFXS2QXDIL4JUO2KKQCPTOF2D5AX5M3R2VH5NM2ZUSXIXGP4WPMVTR sha256 6 30') Do Set "hash=%%A"
```

Easy way to feel dumb is when the answer is so simple. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler answer is to add "clean" parameter at the end of the command (as described in Token2's documentation):

> - the last argument is optional, if argument equals to 'loop' , the tool will stay launched recalculating the current OTP until stopped with Ctrl+C, if the argument is **'clean' the tool will produce the OTP only**

So the code below:

```
t2otp.exe QQRZO4QIGPJFXS2QXDIL4JUO2KKQCPTOF2D5AX5M3R2VH5NM2ZUSXIXGP4WPMVTR sha256 6 30 clean
```

Will give you only the OTP (6 digits in your example)